# Worker thread unable to update the UI on Motorola V3

Tags: multithreading, user-interface, java-me, motorola

I'm working on a J2ME application that should be ported to different vendors phones. So far, the application is working fine, except on the Motorola V3 (this is the only Motorola phone I have tried).

The problem is that when I start a new Thread, and when the thread tries to update the graphics (by calling repaint()), the graphic system is stack.

Some useful info:
- I'm obtaining the display in the constructor of the Midlet, and reusing it during the application lifespan.
- There is only one class extending Canvas. Every drawing happens here. When I want the graphics repainted, I call the repaint() method, either from the UI thread or from another Worker thread. As far as I know, every thread can access the UI without problems.
- I tried a fix where, in the beginning of the app, I take the name of the running (UI) thread and store it for later use. Before repaint() is called, I check if the current thread's name equals to the UI thread's name. If it odes, then I do `repaint()`, else I do:

```
display.callSerially(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        repaint();
    }
});
```

Can you point to me any specifics in the Motorola's implemenation of J2ME? How can I solve this problem with threads updating the UI?

Thanks,
Zlatko

Answer (score 3):

Unlike Swing, the MIDP user interface APIs are thread-safe. This means you don't have to use callSerially to force things to run on the UI thread. There are reports that callSerially doesn't work well on some Motorola devices, so your best bet is to just call repaint by itself.

Note that repaint is just a suggestion to the system to do the repainting. If you want to force the repaints to occur immediately, you have to call the serviceRepaints method.

A good discussion of MIDP UI event handling can be found [here](http://java.sun.com/javame/reference/apis/jsr118/javax/microedition/lcdui/package-summary.html#events).

Comment: Thanks for your response. My initial approach was to directly update the UI from a worker thread as you propose, having in mind the spec you have mentioned. It was not working. That's what initiated me to look for other solutions (including the one I wrote in my post).

Comment: To make my use-case more clear: There is an image showing on app startup for the purpose of splash screen. At that moment, I spawn a new Thread that waits for 5 seconds, then changes the image that should be used by the paint() method and calls repaint(). However, the second image never shows up, but the first one (splash) does. It seems like the repaint() is not executed the second time or it blocks (This code runs perfectly on many other devices). Any ideas?

Comment: It may be that the event thread is blocked. Can you show us the code?

Comment: Please, take a look at the following URL for formatted and syntax-colored code: http://www.copypastecode.com/62605/ This is adapted version of the code in order to show the concept, although the real code is more complex. If something is not clear, I would be happy to explain.

Comment: Now I don't understand why you've created that CanvasManager class. It's like you're trying to manage screens yourself instead of letting the system do it. I would get rid of that stuff and just use the normal Display methods to push and pop screens. For the splash screen, use a Canvas but start the timer thread in the showNotify() method. The timer thread then simply sets the display to the appropriate screen when the time's expired.

Comment: There is a reason why I'm not calling display.setCurrent(...) for every screen I need in the app. On Nokia phones (especially N95) this results in white screen for a few milliseconds between screen transitions and it is noticeable. However, I don't do anything fancy in CanvasManager, only take new Screen and reuse the same Displayable with its paint method. As far as I know, showNotify() will be called only when display.setCurrent() call is used, right?

Comment: Ah, OK, I see, was wondering. Well, I don't see anything obviously wrong so this is probably some kind of bug. You might still try moving the timer into showNotify, which will get called just before the canvas is about to be shown. Then in your timer thread try calling serviceRepaints() right after the call to repaint().